# Read information from CMD, browser using windows UI automation

Tags: winforms, ui-automation

I can understand how UI automation can help retrieve information from text boxes within windows forms applications. How can I retrieve information however from command prompt tools and web browsers? I have a telnet session that I would like to read data from as well as a simple web based tool with plain html. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I don't think there's an easy way to interact with console programs using the UIA API, and web browsers, while possible, would be time-consuming to deal with.  But other libraries can help.

Are you using C#?  If so, for console applications, you can probably use the Process class if your automated test are simple - here's an old post about the same topic:

[Command line automation – expect equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169943/command-line-automation-in-c-net-expect-equivalent)

I'm actually still searching for a free Expect-like C# library.  Haven't spent too much time looking yet, though.

For web automation, I suggest using the Selenium C# client driver - as far as I know, it should do what you need:

http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html

http://seleniumhq.org/download/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think looking on the web for an answer everyone agrees this is quite tricky. I am using C# and I am currently looking the info you sent me.